# Why can't i download something from Ubuntu software Center

Tags: software-center

I recently received my new pc  preinstalled with ubuntu 14.04 and when I try and download someting from the Software center it doesnt download it stalls or something please help im new at Ubuntu

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to download?

Comment: I'm trying to download steam also google chrome and when I allow it to download by entering my password it just says "waiting"

Comment: Can you open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam`?

Comment: Dragon2fly when i do sudo apt-get update it says unable to lock the administration directory

Comment: Could you tell the output of this command `ps aux | grep apt` ?

Comment: what? sorry i don't really understand

Comment: ^Ubuntu and its features

Comment: terminal is your friend! (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `ps aux | grep apt` and press `Enter`

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: says grep: ?: No such file or directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: it says exactly that when i try to do sudo apt-get update

Comment: Stop saying in comments please, [edit] and add output. Use copy paste

Answer (score 0):

This may work,
 Type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If that did not work, try restarting.

Comment: it says "Unable to lock the administration directory"

Comment: restart might fix

Comment: i have been turning off and on no change :(

Comment: still getting the same "Unable to lock..."???

Comment: yes sadly i dont know what to do

Comment: @ChristianNino Are you using in guest session???